# Issues with converting .tex file to PDF on the ScholarOne manuscripts submission system

Tags: compiling

I am submitting my manuscript to a journal that is using ScholarOne Manuscripts submission system. However when upload my .tex file along with the .bib and Class file, I get the following error:

```
The file failed conversion and will not be available as part of the proof. Please delete it and upload it again. For more information visit the FAQ <Read More ...> or contact support via the 'Help' link.
```

The log file can be found here: https://textuploader.com/1rj7q

Please note that I am using a template provided by the journal and that the file converts to PDF perfectly fine on my PC without any errors.

Comment: The error in the log seems clear: your document is loading package `stix` and that's not on the server.

Comment: And please note that they use a totaly outdated TeX distribution: `pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)`, the current one is TeX Live 2019, `-1.40.20` ...